# Asset catalog with PDF Vector Image does not export @3x resolution for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcasset

I am trying to use PDF Image in my Asset Catalogs files to automatically generate png files. This feature as been presented in WWDC 2014, video 411 (What's new in Interface Builder)

On iOS XCode is supposed to render the PDF to @1x, @2x, @3x PNG at the build time.
It checked at my generated archives using cartool (cannot post the link as I lack reputation on SO) and it seems only the @1x and @2x resolutions are generated.

I looked a bit around the internet and found [this post](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/) and [this one](http://invisiblepixels.org/InvisibleWords/2014/11/02/vector-images-in-the-asset-catalogue/). The later provides a sample project, which I tried. It also only generated those 2 resolutions.

Did anyone tried this and lucky generated @3x images?

Regards

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Found a fork that someone made.  Seems to have worked for me to also get the @3x PNG files.  Hope this helps!

https://github.com/G-P-S/cartool